# ConTeXt and Metafun: Framed enumeration with counter as part of overlay

Tags: context, framed, metafun

How do you make an `enumeration` where the `enumeration` counter appears within a frame decorated with Metafun?

The idea is to have something similar to an example on pg. 144 of the Metafun manual:

[image]

Except that "Zapf (1)" would be a counter rather a manual label.

Here is the code that reproduces the example with the manual frame:

```
\startuseMPgraphic{FunnyFrame}
  picture p ; numeric w, h, o ;
  p := textext.rt(\MPstring{FunnyFrame}) ;
  w := OverlayWidth ; h := OverlayHeight ; o := BodyFontSize ;
  p := p shifted (2o,h-ypart center p) ; draw p ;
  drawoptions (withpen pencircle scaled 1pt withcolor .625red) ;
  draw (2o,h)--(0,h)--(0,0)--(w,0)--(w,h)--(xpart urcorner p,h) ;
  draw boundingbox p ;
  setbounds currentpicture to unitsquare xyscaled(w,h) ;
\stopuseMPgraphic

\defineoverlay[FunnyFrame][\useMPgraphic{FunnyFrame}]
\defineframedtext[FunnyText][frame=off,background=FunnyFrame]
\def\StartFrame{\startFunnyText}
\def\StopFrame {\stopFunnyText }
\def\FrameTitle#1%
{\setMPtext{FunnyFrame}{\hbox spread 1em{\hss\strut#1\hss}}}
\setMPtext{FunnyFrame}{}

\starttext

\FrameTitle{Zapf (1)}
\StartFrame
Coming back to the use of typefaces in electronic
publishing: many of the new typographers receive their
knowledge and information about the rules of typography from
books, from computer magazines or the instruction manuals
which they get with the purchase of a PC or software.
\StopFrame

\stoptext
```

I was able to make enough progress to add an answer to this problem, but I'm still unsure if it's the right way to go.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `\wrappedcurrentconstruction` instead of `MPstring/MPtext`. With `\wrappedcurrentconstruction`, the references also work correctly.

```
\startuseMPgraphic{FunnyFrame}
    picture p ; numeric w, h, o ;
    p := textext.rt("\wrappedcurrentconstruction");

    w := OverlayWidth ; h := OverlayHeight ; o := BodyFontSize ;
    p := p shifted (2o,h-ypart center p); 
    draw p ;

    path b;
    b := boundingbox p enlarged (o/10);

    drawoptions (withpen pencircle scaled 1pt withcolor .625red) ;
    draw (2o,h)--(0,h)--(0,0)--(w,0)--(w,h)--(xpart urcorner b,h) ;
    draw b;

    setbounds currentpicture to OverlayBox ;
\stopuseMPgraphic

\defineoverlay[FunnyFrame][\useMPgraphic{FunnyFrame}]

\defineframedtext
  [FunnyFramedText]
  [
    frame=off,
    background=FunnyFrame,
    offset=\bodyfontsize,
    width=\textwidth,
  ]

\defineenumeration[Counter]
  [
    alternative=empty,
    before=\startFunnyFramedText,
    after=\stopFunnyFramedText,
  ]

\starttext
\startCounter
  Coming back to the use of typefaces in electronic
  publishing: many of the new typographers receive their
  knowledge and information about the rules of typography from
  books, from computer magazines or the instruction manuals
  which they get with the purchase of a PC or software.
\stopCounter

\startCounter
  Coming back to the use of typefaces in electronic
  publishing: many of the new typographers receive their
  knowledge and information about the rules of typography from
  books, from computer magazines or the instruction manuals
  which they get with the purchase of a PC or software.
\stopCounter
\stoptext
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Effectively, the answer relies on referencing the counter within the frame using `\getnumber` and omitting the default `enumeration` label.

```
% Code from manual
\startuseMPgraphic{FunnyFrame}
  picture p ; numeric w, h, o ;
  p := textext.rt(\MPstring{FunnyFrame}) ;
  w := OverlayWidth ; h := OverlayHeight ; o := BodyFontSize ;
  p := p shifted (2o,h-ypart center p) ; draw p ;
  drawoptions (withpen pencircle scaled 1pt withcolor .625red) ;
  draw (2o,h)--(0,h)--(0,0)--(w,0)--(w,h)--(xpart urcorner p,h) ;
  draw boundingbox p ;
  setbounds currentpicture to unitsquare xyscaled(w,h) ;
\stopuseMPgraphic

\defineoverlay[FunnyFrame][\useMPgraphic{FunnyFrame}]
\defineframedtext[FunnyText][frame=off,background=FunnyFrame]
\def\FrameTitle#1%
{\setMPtext{FunnyFrame}{\hbox spread 1em{\hss\strut#1\hss}}}
\setMPtext{FunnyFrame}{}

% Add the enumeration
\defineenumeration
  [Counter]
  [text=,
   alternative=empty,
   before={\FrameTitle{Counter \getnumber[Counter]} 
           \startFunnyText},
   after={\stopFunnyText}]

\starttext

\startCounter
Coming back to the use of typefaces in electronic
publishing: many of the new typographers receive their
knowledge and information about the rules of typography from
books, from computer magazines or the instruction manuals
which they get with the purchase of a PC or software.
\stopCounter

\startCounter
Coming back to the use of typefaces in electronic
publishing: many of the new typographers receive their
knowledge and information about the rules of typography from
books, from computer magazines or the instruction manuals
which they get with the purchase of a PC or software.
\stopCounter

\stoptext
```

**Edit:** Replaced `alternative=inleft` with `alternative=empty` as per comment.

The result:

[image]

Comment: You can use `alternative=empty` instead of `alternative=inleft`. The `alternative=empty` only sets the style and color of the title text.