# Fancy colored boxes in ConTeXt MKIV

Tags: context, fancybox

Can someone explain how to create fancy boxes like this in ConTeXt MKIV and probably with MetaFun?

[image: Theorem Box]

According to @JairoADelRio link and MetaFun manual it is easy to change title text, to round and to change the background color of the title box.

However, any change I make only appears in title box. Why is that so? What do I miss? And how to round and to change the background color of the the content box?

Plus, how to get space between title and the box around it?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/438588/context-and-metafun-framed-enumeration-with-counter-as-part-of-overlay

Comment: Well, that gives the answer but it does not really explain how to achieve it from scratch.

Comment: @dgdkhB62 to achieve it from scratch you can start from scratch, copy the code in the answer to the other question, and you're done, right? Or are you interested in finding out which line in the code does what, or are there lines you don't understand? In that case you could edit your current question into something like "I tried this code and I don't understand lines X and Y, what do they do?" or maybe "I tried this code, how do I apply a background color and rounded corners" or something else you are interested in.

Comment: Section 4 of Metafun manual explain how to do colored framed content via overlays: http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/metafun-p.pdf