# Questions about fancyboxes in ConTeXt with MetaFun

Tags: context, theorems, fancybox, metafun

I'm trying to reproduce something like that with MetaFun:

[image]

For now [with](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/438588/context-and-metafun-framed-enumeration-with-counter-as-part-of-overlay) [these](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/486078/is-there-any-alternative-for-tcolorbox-in-context) [links](https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2018/090550.html), I managed to get that:
[image]

```
\definecolor[darkblue][r=20,g=30,b=50]
\startuseMPgraphic{MPTheoremFrame}
    % Useful values
    numeric w, h, o, b ;
    w := OverlayWidth ; h := OverlayHeight ; o := BodyFontSize ;
    b := 1pt ; % border size

    path theorembox ;% contentbox ;


    % LABEL
    picture theorem ;
    %% Get label and counter
    theorem := textext.rt("~\bf\ss\currentconstructionsample~\getnumber[\currentconstruction]~") ;
    %% Shift it to the right place
    theorem := theorem shifted (o-b/2,h+3(o-b)/2) ;


    % THEOREMBOX
    %% Set theorembox as a boundingbox around title
    theorembox := boundingbox theorem enlarged o;
    %% Set theorembox background color
    fill theorembox withcolor darkblue ;
    %% Draw label/counter with the right color inside theorembox
    draw theorem withcolor white ;


    % THEOREMTITLE
    picture title;
    %% Get theorem title
    title := textext.rt("~\bf\ss\currentconstructiontitle~") ;
    % Shift theorem title next to theorembox
    title := title shifted (bbwidth(theorembox), h+3(o-b)/2);
    % Draw theorem title
    draw title withcolor darkblue ;


    % CONTENT
    drawoptions (withpen pencircle scaled b withcolor darkblue) ;
    draw (0,h)--(0,h)--(0,0)--(w,0)--(w,h)--(xpart urcorner theorembox, h) ;


    setbounds currentpicture to OverlayBox ;
\stopuseMPgraphic

\defineoverlay[MPTheoremFrame][\useMPgraphic{MPTheoremFrame}]

\defineframedtext[TheoremFramedText][frame=off,
                                     background=MPTheoremFrame,
                                     offset=\bodyfontsize,
                                     width=\textwidth]
\defineenumeration[theorem][title=yes,
                            text={\labeltext{theorem}},
                            alternative=empty,
                            before=\startTheoremFramedText,
                            after=\stopTheoremFramedText,
                            prefix=yes,
                            way=bysection,
                            prefixsegments={chapter:section}]
```

As you can see, there is some issues I can't fix:

- boxes are above the sections names and text : here there is a section named "Test" hidden by the theorem box
- boxes are above each others
- There is a little glitch with the labelbox and the content box...

Also:

- <s>how to place the theorem name outside the titlebox?</s>
- is there a proper way to use these boxes in margins?
- how can I edit the content box? (background, changing fonts, etc...)

Comment: It's done with ConTeXt MKIV.

Comment: And since I already have a large document written in ConTeXt I am not sure I want to move in LaTeX with lualatex.

Comment: Basically, you are placing the theorem number and theorem title using metapost but are telling metapost that the image that is has drawn has the bounding box of the _content_ of the theorem. So, no space is reserved for it. The simplest fix is to add `before={\blank[2*line]}` in `\defineenumeration`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an altogether different and much simpler approach to get the same result.

The example is simply the `alternative=top` with a left frame and a bottom frame, which is easy to achieve by wrapping the theorem inside a framedtext.

The tricky part is the fancy title. ConTeXt provides three hooks to wrap a command around an enumeration:

- `numbercommand`, which is applied only to the number,
- `titlecommand`, which is applied to the title only
- `headcommand`, which is applied to both the number and the title.

So, all you need to do is set the `numbercommand` as a frame with blue background, and you are done.

Here is the complete code:

```
\definecolor[darkblue][b=0.8]

\definemeasure[frameoffset][2ex]
\definemeasure[rulethickness][2pt]

\defineframedtext
  [theoremframe]
  [
    frame=off,
    leftframe=on,
    bottomframe=on,
    framecolor=darkblue,
    rulethickness=\measure{rulethickness},
    width=broad,
    offset=overlay,
    loffset=\measure{frameoffset},
    boffset=\measure{frameoffset},
    toffset=-\measure{rulethickness},
  ]

\defineframed
  [headframed]
  [
    background=color,
    backgroundcolor=darkblue,
    foregroundcolor=white,
    frame=off,
    toffset=1ex,
    boffset=1ex,
    roffset=1ex,
    loffset=\measure{frameoffset},
    location=low,
  ]

\defineenumeration
  [theorem]
  [
    text=Theorem,
    % Number
    prefix=yes,
    prefixsegments={chapter:section},
    way=bysection,
    numbercommand={\hskip-\measure{frameoffset}\relax\headframed},
    % Title
    title=yes,
    titlecolor=darkblue,
    titleleft=,
    titleright=,
    % Frame
    before=\starttheoremframe,
    after=\stoptheoremframe,
  ]

\starttext
\startsection[title=An example theorem]
\starttheorem[title={Pythagorean Theorem}]
  Let $V$ be an inner product space. If $(u,v) \in V^2$ are orthogonal to each
  other, then
  \startformula
    \lVert u + v \rVert^2 = \lVert u \rVert^2 + \lVert v \rVert^2.
  \stopformula
\stoptheorem
\stopsection
\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]